# ApiKey security on different versions of endpoint deployments

Tags: flask, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints, swagger-ui

Some context: We have a flask application running on kubernetes(GKE). We use google cloud endpoints to manage the access and key management to our api. We create documentation through flask-restplus and use this to configure our endpoints. An important must have is that our swagger UI documentation must be accessible without an ApiKey so we set "x-google-allow": "all" in our endpoints config. All of the above works.

The problem: We want to deploy a major change in our API so we opted for a new version [described here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/versioning-an-api#backwards-incompatible). This means a new base path. So we create 2 endpoints config files one with base path /api/1/ and one with /api/2, both have the same host and the "x-google-allow": "all" flag.

Deploying with the 2 configs works but only the swagger UI of version 2  (/api/2/doc/) is available. If we want to access the documentation of the older version (/api/1/doc/) we need an API key ( and then it returns a blank screen). If we host the same flask application locally we can access both documentation pages. We need to have the documentation of both versions available (we have other parties consuming our API's)

I tried changing the "x-google-allow": "all" and then adding a path to the /doc page with "security":[] in the endpoints config but the problem persists.

Comment: Hello Georges, Google Cloud Support here. I saw that you filed also a support ticket and we are working on it. When you receive the answer about your question, please feel free to share it on this page.